# Highcharts and JSON data from PHP

Tags: php, json, highcharts

I have a simple PHP script that collects information from a database and echoes the data with `json_encode()`. The result is this:

```
{"21":"1222","22":"3569","23":"1380"}
```

Where 21 is the port, and 2222 is the occurrences of that port number. What I am trying to do is a pie chart of this data, whereas the first string is the key and the second one is the number.

The graph is done through this and my container is the default div with id container.

```
jQuery.get('data.php', null, function (data) {
    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'pie'
        },
        series: [{}]
    };
    options.series[0].data = data;
    options.series[0].type = 'pie';
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

I am pretty sure I have messed up the formatting of the data. When writing this I realised that I have forgotten to put the sum in, so the pie knows how to format the pie accordingly. That would be nice to get some assistance with as well.

How can you do this in the most efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the json_encode you should set JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK parameter. Morever in the objects you need to have x / y values so as a result it should be:

```
[{x: 21, y: 1222},{x: 22, y: 3569},{x: 23, y: 1380}]
```

Comment: Thanks. You pointed me in the correct direction! The fix was to change the php script that returns the data and not just return the result from fetchAll but to add some params to the data as you have shown above.